# How to elegantly handle multiple .find() checks in an if check elegantly?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

So right now I have a line in my code with multiple value checks that gets extremely bulky. How would I declutter it?

```
if string.find(a) != -1 and string.find(b) != -1 string.find(b) != -1 and string.find(c)==-1 and string.find(d)==-1 string not in list:
```

I tried to handle everything in a for loop, which turned out to be quite the hassle to fulfill many conditions, which had me return to the long row above.

Answer (score 1):

An example using `map` and `all`

```py
a = "abc 123 321"
i = ["abc", "123", "321"]

if all(map(lambda f: f in a, i)):
    print("All elements of i are in a")
```

Comment: `map(lambda` these days is much better done with comprehensions or generator expressions.  `all`, `any`  on a generator expression tends to be a very efficient, clean way to aggregate multiple checks.